# Dimension of kernel for nilpotent transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations, nilpotence

Let $T:R^n\rightarrow R^n$ be a nilpotent transformation with index n. (e.g. $T^n=0$). Is it true that for all $n\geq k \geq 0$,    $\dim Ker T^k = 0$? How can that be shown?

Answer (score 1):

We can generate counterexamples with square matrices. For example, take
$$
A=
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
A^2 &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
&
A^3 &=
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
&
A^4 &= 
\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}
This shows that $A$ is nilpotent with index $4$. What can we say about the nullspaces of $A$, $A^2$, and $A^3$? Do you see how this example generalizes?

Many many other counterexamples can be constructed by choosing an invertible $P$ and taking $B=PAP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For $k = 0$ this is true because $T^0 = \mathrm{id}_{\mathbb{R}^m}$. If we are dealing with $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m = 0$ this is also true.

If $m \geq 1$ and $k \geq 1$ then this is false: Notice that if $\ker T = 0$ then $T$ is injective and thus $T^k$ is injective for all $k \geq 1$, contradicting $T^n = 0$. So $\ker T \neq 0$. For all $k \geq 1$ we have $\ker T^k \supseteq \ker T$, so $\ker T^k \neq 0$ for every $k \geq 1$.

In fact
$$
 0
 = \ker T^0
 \subsetneq \ker T
 \subsetneq \ker T^2
 \subsetneq \dotsb
 \subsetneq \ker T^{n-1}
 \subsetneq \ker T^n
 = \mathbb{R}^m,
$$
is stricly increasing, assuming that $n = \min \{k \geq 0 \mid T^k = 0\}$.